# Is it legal to use col and d-flex classes together with Bootstrap 5?

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

Can I use `col` and `d-flex` together? I`m centering the class "description" combining them.

```
  <section class="container-fluid mb-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md order-md-1 d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="description col col-xxl-8 text-center p-5">
            <h2 class="display-5">Museum of Candy</h2>
            <img src="imgs/lolli_icon.png" alt="" class="d-none d-xl-inline-block">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit pariatur libero repellat earum, atque sint perferendis nostrum rem? Labore nemo molestias at ipsum exercitationem dignissimos doloremque cupiditate dolore, saepe atque!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md px-0 order-md-0">
        <img src="imgs/milk.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no *laws* in usage of a library. The `d-flex` class makes the column a flex *container* as well (though it may already be). Use it if it fits your needs.